# Desktop File to open terminal with an alternative prompt

Tags: 14.04, bash, .desktop, prompt

I want to create a *.desktop* file, which opens a terminal with a prompt, that display the current time and the current working directory in green color. I achieved this via the command:

```
$ PS1="\033[0;32m(\$(date +%H:%M:%S)) \W$ \033[0m"
```

gives this prompt:

```
(14:30:12) media$
```

For this command I created following *.desktop* file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Open Terminal
Comment=Open Terminal with modified Prompt
Exec=bash -c 'export PS1="\033[0;32m(\$(date +%H:%M:%S)) \W$ \033[0m";$SHELL'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

I think I do something wrong at passing the variable, but I do not know what exactly, can you help me in finding out what the problem is?

Reason for this is gaining several `.desktop` files with which I can open different terminals with different prompts.

Comment: I tried many things with and without `$SHELL`. This variable ensures that the terminal keeps open but still I dont have any clue. Also tried around with `export`,`env` and and and :-) This is important for me since I sometimes have to work with very long paths and therefore want to have an alternative terminal prompt. So workarounds are welcome, too, if still comfortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but may be less adopted solution.

### Troubleshooting

From my observation, there are two issues: `$SHELL` is being called after `export PS1` command, and color bash prompts are improperly coded

- Running `$SHELL` will create a new prompt. This caused whatever done before i.e. `export PS1` becomes useless, since the new prompt will overwrite the earlier ones.
- Another issue is probably some typos. I couldn't find any reason for leaving the one-sided square bracket `[` being opened.

[This HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) noted that it should be enclosed.

> As mentioned before, non-printing escape sequences have to be enclosed in **`\[\033[`** and **`\]`**. For colour escape sequences, they should also be followed by a lowercase **`m`**.

### The workaround

Use separate `.bashrc` file per different `PS1` configuration. Then, run `bash` that calls another `bash` with `--init-file` option to run prompt using the separate `.bashrc` file.

Follow the steps below.

1. Create an empty file with different name i.e. `.bashrc2` in **Home** directory.
2. Open the file in a text editor, copy and paste the following (revised).

   ```
    export PS1="\[\033[0;32m\](\$(date +%H:%M:%S)) \W$ \[\033[0m\]"
   ```
3. Save and close the file.
4. Create another empty file with different name i.e. `shortcut2.desktop` on **Desktop**.
5. Open the file in a text editor, copy and paste the following.

   ```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=Terminal 2
    Comment=Open Terminal with .bashrc2
    Exec=bash -c 'bash --init-file $HOME/.bashrc2'
    Icon=utilities-terminal
    Terminal=true
    Type=Application
    Categories=Application;
   ```
6. Save and close the file.
7. Finally, double-click the shortcut (now appears as **Terminal 2** on **Desktop**) to run the prompt.

Repeat the steps for other configurations, if any, by giving different names i.e. `.bashrc3`, `shortcut3.desktop` and such.

### The unexplained

Running `bash --init-file $HOME/.bashrc2` alone will fail to include the `PS1` configuration. The resulting prompt will be discolored and will fall back to `[\u@\h:\w]$` format. In other words, the `.bashrc2` file is entirely ignored. This is why nested shell is required.

Comment: Ok nice workaround by creating 2 two `~/.bashrc` files and open them like this. I should be able to replace `~/.bashrc` with `~/.profile`, shouldnt I?

Comment: No, this workaround does *not* replace existing files and I don't see any reason to replace them. The `--init-file` option only instructs `bash` to use the specified file i.e. `.bashrc2`. Any existing file will remain. So, if you run the Terminal normally from applications menu, it can still use the existing `.bashrc` file. For both cases, I believe the same `.profile` is used.

Comment: No I meant that in your code i can use `.profile` instead of `.bashrc`. Is this correct? Would be nice since my `.profile` is modified already and I don't have to commit 2 changes then :-)

Comment: I will just try it. Otherwise I will just use this. THanks for your effort anyway.